# Nuget update fails when there is more than one solution file pointing to the same package.config

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm having more than one solution file for my project each pointing to a different target frameworks.
I'm able to restore the nugets for each solution using nuget restore  command.
The problem arises when i try to use the update command.
**Found multiple project files for package** warning is shown and my packages are not updated to the latest version.

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: which frame work do you want to use?

Comment: multiple solution files or multiple project (csproj) files including the same packages.config file?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm having multiple csproj and solution files.I'm maintaining project files for each framework.

Comment: @VedPrakash I'm having 4.5 +

Comment: Did it ever work to update nuget packages? that layout is unsupported by tooling AFAIK

Comment: @MartinUllrich. No it never worked. If i remove other solutions from the directory and maintain one its updating properly.